# MvcSiteMapProvider - Using a custom URL to access the sitemap

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm going to preface this by saying that I'm new to .NET and C#, so this may be a relatively simple problem but so far I've been unable to resolve it on my own. I'm learning .NET MVC in my own time, but I've had to pick it up at work due to various circumstances and therefore my knowledge and understanding of it is currently fragmented, though I've so far managed by just looking things up.

I also can't give specific names or URLs as it pertains to a client with whom an NDA is in effect so I'l have to keep it generic.

The situation:
I have an application (a custom CMS if you will) that's been built internally and used for client projects. This application makes use of [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) to both generate breadcrumbs if necessary, and provide an XML sitemap for bots to crawl.
One of the instances also routes through Akamai in order to make a subdomain look like a subfolder, but as a result of various redirects and reverse-proxy rules the XML Sitemap is no longer accessible at its default URL. I've been handed this problem to resolve and have been struggling with finding solution.

What I want to do is change the URL of the sitemap so that it appears to bots to sit in the same virtual subdirectory as the rest of the application.
Example:
***www.application.com/sitemap.xml*** would become something like ***www.application.com/blog/sitemap.xml***

What I've tried:
1 - I tried defining a custom route specifically for the sitemap, but whether down to my own lack of knowledge or other factors this attempt also proved to not work. The following code is what I attempted for that:

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "CustomSitemap",
      "blog/sitemap.xml",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**Mvc.Sitemap**

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" route="CustomSitemap">
    <!-- Providers go here ->
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

What I was expecting was for the sitemap to just become available at the URL I defined in RouteConfig.cs but this didn't happen. If it's relevant, there's no file called **HomeController.cs** but the default route seems to work fine by referencing it anyway.

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

2 - I also tried moving the Mvc.Sitemap file to another directory to see if that worked but the URL for it didn't change either.

3 - I looked through the MvcSiteMapProvider documentation but there was nothing that directly answered the question I have. While there may be something in there that I've overlooked due to a lack of understanding.

Thanks for taking a look, and I apologise for the somewhat vague nature of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should disable the routes that are added by `MvcSiteMapProvider`.

### Internal DI

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableSitemapsXml" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

### External DI

Remove this line:

```
// Register the Sitemaps routes for search engines
//XmlSiteMapController.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

## Customizing XML Sitemap Routing

Then it is simply a matter of registering the routes for the `XmlSiteMapController`. You need to have 2 in order to take into account paging (when you reach 35,000 pages it automatically uses a [sitemap index](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index) and multiple sitemap pages).

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "XmlSitemap",
            url: "blog/sitemap.xml",
            defaults: new { controller = "XmlSiteMap", action = "Index", page = 0 }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "XmlSitemap-Paged",
            url: "blog/sitemap-{page}.xml",
            defaults: new { controller = "XmlSiteMap", action = "Index", page = 0 }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

> **NOTE:** This example shows you how to add a subdirectory to the route. But do note that [the specification is clear that you cannot use a sitemap file to reference pages above its current directory](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#location), so you should be aware of the limitations of the protocol if you decide to implement this.
>
> **The location of a Sitemap file determines the set of URLs that can be included in that Sitemap. A Sitemap file located at http://example.com/catalog/sitemap.xml can include any URLs starting with http://example.com/catalog/ but can not include URLs starting with http://example.com/images/.**

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly.  I'll try this out and see if I can get it working.

Would this method require the use of dependency injections?

Comment: Nope, Dependeny Injection is not required to do this (but you can use it if you want to).